# Include on hasMany association only returning one of many results in sequelize nodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am use sequelize ORM for node js. Include on hasMany association only returning one of many results. I have 2 table "album" and "album_tag".
1:M relation between album and album_tag. I am trying to get all record for album_tag table but i can't. my code is here

CODE:

```
    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    var sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', '', {  // configuration  }  });

    const db = {};    
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;  
    db.sequelize = sequelize;

    db.album = require('./../model/definitions/album')(sequelize, Sequelize);  // col: id, name, status
    db.albumTag = require('./../model/definitions/albumTag')(sequelize, Sequelize);  // col: album_id,tag_id

    db.album.hasMany(db.albumTag, {foreignKey: 'album_id'});
    db.albumTag.removeAttribute('id');    

    db.album.findAll({where: {id: 22},  
      include: [{          
      model: db.albumTag,
      required: true 
    }],        
    }).then(function(result) {
      callback(200,result);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      callback(100,error);
    }).done();
```

result is

```
 [{"id": 22,
   "name": "Test",
   "status": "Active",            
   "album_tag": [{
       "album_id": 22,
       "tag_id": 10
   }]
 }]
```

but i need this result

```
[{"id": 22,
  "name": "Test",
  "status": "Active",            
  "album_tag": [{
      "album_id": 22,
      "tag_id": 10
    },{
      "album_id": 22,
      "tag_id": 11
    },{
      "album_id": 22,
      "tag_id": 12
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Do you have `id` key defined in `album_tag`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one association.
Please add this:

```
db.albumTag.hasOne(db.album, {foreignKey: 'album_id'});
```

So at the end it looks like this:

```
db.album.hasMany(db.albumTag, {foreignKey: 'album_id'});
db.albumTag.hasOne(db.album, {foreignKey: 'album_id'});
```